# How to cast GETDATE() to be only time ignore day,month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server, getdate

I have a table for store takt-time. It's compound with "day_shift(1)" and "night_shift(0)" like below.

[image]

If I put current time(by using GETDATE() function ).
I need to know this current time is "day(1)" or "night(0)". my query like this.

```
SELECT [day_shift_flag]   
FROM  [company_working_time]
WHERE   GETDATE() BETWEEN [start_time] AND[end_time]
```

But it can't found because a date received from GETDATE() isn't '1900-01-01'
How to compare a only time and ignore day,month,year.
What should I do?

Comment: Depending on your version of SQL-Server, there is a TIME datatype you could use instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can cast a DateTime as a Time data type. For example:

```
SELECT 
    [day_shift_flag]   
FROM  [company_working_time]
WHERE   
CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) BETWEEN CAST([start_time] AS TIME) AND CAST([end_time] AS TIME)
```

Answer (score 2):

By Following Way You can Ignore the  day,month,year

```
       SELECT [day_shift_flag]   
        FROM  [company_working_time]
        WHERE   DatePart(HH,GETDATE()) BETWEEN DatePart(HH,[start_time]) AND DatePart(HH,[end_time])
```